# How to find information in json file what i need and print those file names?

Tags: python, json

I have a silly question.
So basically, there is allot of JSON files and, for example, i need find to only the JSON files that contains only that information i need now  and print those file names that contains that information what i need?

So there's an example:
i have an directory where the files are at
and this is the information what JSON files contain

```
{
    "version": "1.0.4",
    "room": {
        "index": 2,
        "label": "Bedroom",
        "score": 0.999368429,
        "threshold": 0.6,
        "raw": {
            "Balcony": {
                "index": 0,
                "score": 0.000324130058
            },
            "Bathroom": {
                "index": 1,
                "score": 8.77380371e-05
            },
            "Bedroom": {
                "index": 2,
                "score": 0.999368429
            },
            "Dining Room": {
                "index": 3,
                "score": 0.000696450472
            },
            "Garage": {
                "index": 4,
                "score": 0.000141739845
            },
            "Hallway": {
                "index": 5,
                "score": 3.37660313e-05
            },
            "Kitchen": {
                "index": 6,
                "score": 4.11570072e-05
            },
            "Laundry Room": {
                "index": 7,
                "score": 9.4473362e-06
            }
,...       
        }
    }
}
```

Now i need to find all JSON files that contain `"label": "Bedroom"`  and print those file names.
Its just for me. I'm learning. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What code to do this do you already have?

Comment: `grep -l '"label": "Bedroom"' *.json` will do this brillianty (if "label": "Bedroom" is on a single line). Of course, if you have `grep` installed.

Comment: @9769953 For now i have only this `import os, json
path_to_json = r'\my\path\blablabla'

json_files =  [data_json for data_json in os.listdir(path_to_json) if data_json.endswith('.room-class.json')]

print(json_files)` It finds all files named .room-class.json Tried couple other things. Didn't work

Comment: I have. Thank you. I appreciate your help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
import glob
import json

file_dir = 'wkdir1/' #file location
files = glob.glob(file_dir+'*.json')
key = 'Bedroom'
files_with_key = []
for fl in files:
    f = open(fl)
    json_data = json.load(f)
    if key == json_data['room']['label']:
        files_with_key.append(fl)

print(files_with_key)
```

Comment: Console shows this `runfile('C:/Users/maxib/Desktop/python/untitled9.py', wdir='C:/Users/maxib/Desktop/python')
[] `

Comment: Please edit file_dir variable with your json files location.

Comment: @Rasin_C I already did that . Thank you for answering :)

Comment: your console is returning an empty array. 
can you print the files variable...

Comment: It shows "os imported but unused".

Comment: sorry about the os import. that is not necessary. try to print files variable. and verify whether it is able to list the json files in your file location.

Comment: @Rasin_C still nothing

Comment: which means code is not able to detect the files...
as a simple solution,

1. get the current working directory. you can use the below code for the same  
`import os
print(os.getcwd())`

2. copy the json folder and script.py to this location

Answer (score -1):

You can loop through the files in the current directory and check if it contains the information you need.

```
import os

# The directory that you want to search in. Let's assume that it is named "data"
DIR = "data"
data = "" # The data to check against. I'm not going to write that here, as it is too long.

for file in os.listdir(DIR):
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        if f.readlines() == data:
            print(file)
            break
```